# Mule: monitoring sub-folders with Mule file endpoint component

Tags: file, directory, mule, endpoint

How Mule provide possibility to polling sub-folders with Mule file endpoint component
As I know there are two approaches: to override createReceiver method and to extend FileMessageReceiver class.
Could you provide hits how I can do it. Decisions are not clear and obvious for me.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the 'recursive' attribute? 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference

Comment: Thank you, working. But I need to save the same folder structure.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but by using recursive it is reading the same folder again and again. Is there a way to stop the File inbound not to read the same file again without deleting it??